# What are the names of all the Angels in Neon Genesis Evangelion?

Tags: neon-genesis-evangelion

In the *Neon Genesis Evangelion* anime, there are about 20 Angels. There's some in Sadamoto's *Evangelion* manga as well, then some different ones in *Rebuild of Evangelion*, and there are others in the other official media (light novels, etc.).

What are all the Angels and their names?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are some Angels which appear in multiple canons, and some which appear only in just one, or even none. To be clear, the various canons are listed at the bottom in a reference list.

#### Main Angels

These Angels appear only in the primary canons:

- [Adam](http://evangelion.wikia.com/wiki/Adam)<sup>[*NGE, M*]</sup>
- [Arael](http://evangelion.wikia.com/wiki/Arael)<sup>[*NGE, M*]</sup>
- [Armisael](http://evangelion.wikia.com/wiki/Armisael)<sup>[*NGE, M*]</sup>
- [Bardiel](http://evangelion.wikia.com/wiki/Bardiel)<sup>[*NGE, RB, M*]</sup>
- [Gaghiel](http://evangelion.wikia.com/wiki/Gaghiel)<sup>[*NGE, M*]</sup>
- [Ireul](http://evangelion.wikia.com/wiki/Ireul)<sup>[*NGE*]</sup>
- [Israfel](http://evangelion.wikia.com/wiki/Israfel)<sup>[*NGE, M*]</sup>
- [Leliel](http://evangelion.wikia.com/wiki/Leliel)<sup>[*NGE*]</sup>
- [Lilin](http://evangelion.wikia.com/wiki/Lilin)<sup>[*NGE, M*]</sup>
- [Lilith](http://evangelion.wikia.com/wiki/Lilith)<sup>[*NGE, RB, M*]</sup>
- [Matarael](http://evangelion.wikia.com/wiki/Matarael)<sup>[*NGE*]</sup>
- [Ramiel](http://evangelion.wikia.com/wiki/Ramiel)<sup>[*NGE, RB, M*]</sup>
- [Sachiel](http://evangelion.wikia.com/wiki/Sachiel)<sup>[*NGE, RB, M*]</sup>
- [Sahaquiel](http://evangelion.wikia.com/wiki/Sahaquiel)<sup>[*NGE, RB, M*]</sup>
- [Sandalphon](http://evangelion.wikia.com/wiki/Sandalphon)<sup>[*NGE*]</sup>
- "[Seventh Angel](http://evangelion.wikia.com/wiki/Seventh_Angel)"<sup>[*RB*]</sup>
- [Shamshel](http://evangelion.wikia.com/wiki/Shamshel)<sup>[*NGE, RB, M*]</sup>
- [Tabris](http://evangelion.wikia.com/wiki/Tabris)<sup>[*NGE, RB, M*] Not known as "Tabris" in *Rebuild*</sup>
- "[Third Angel](http://evangelion.wikia.com/wiki/Third_Angel)"<sup>[*RB*]</sup>
- "[Twelfth Angel](http://evangelion.wikia.com/wiki/Twelfth_Angel)"<sup>[*RB*]</sup>
- [Zeruel](http://evangelion.wikia.com/wiki/Zeruel)<sup>[*NGE, RB, M*]</sup>

#### Secondary Angels

These Angels are not part of the main continuities:

- [Barakijal](http://evangelion.wikia.com/wiki/Barakijal)<sup>[*NWP*]</sup>
- [Iblis](http://evangelion.wikia.com/wiki/Iblis)<sup>[*NWP*]</sup>
- [Insubstantial Angel](http://evangelion.wikia.com/wiki/Insubstantial_Angel)<sup>[*2I*]</sup>
- [An unnamed Angel](http://evangelion.wikia.com/wiki/Unnamed_Angel)<sup>[*2I*]</sup>
- [Shateiel](http://evangelion.wikia.com/wiki/Shateiel)<sup>[C]</sup>
- [Turel](http://evangelion.wikia.com/wiki/Turel)<sup>[C]</sup>
- [Diemay Angel](http://evangelion.wikia.com/wiki/Diemay_Angel) <sup>Fan-made for a Gainax contest</sup>

#### Canon list

- *NGE* - *Neon Genesis Evangelion* (anime)
- *RB* - *Rebuild of Evangelion* (movie series)
- *M* - [*Neon Genesis Evangelion*](http://evangelion.wikia.com/wiki/Neon_Genesis_Evangelion_(manga)) (manga)
- *2I* - [*Second Impression*](http://evangelion.wikia.com/wiki/Neon_Genesis_Evangelion:_Second_Impression) (video game)
- *NWP* - [*RPG: The NERV White Paper*](http://evangelion.wikia.com/wiki/Neon_Genesis_Evangelion_RPG:_The_NERV_White_Paper) (trading card game)
- C - No canon, concept only

#### Further reading

- [Angels - *Evangelion* Wiki](http://evangelion.wikia.com/wiki/Angel#List_of_Angels)
- [List of Angels - EvaGeeks](http://wiki.evageeks.org/Angels#List_of_Angels)